# How to theme output of node_view_multiple()?

Tags: 7, theming

If I want to theme the output of `node_view_multiple()` I can just set the `#theme` element of the renderable array generated by the `node_view_multiple()` function.

But, what if I'm not the one that called the `node_view_multiple()`? Is there a tpl file for that?

A good example would be a taxonomy term page. The `taxonomy-term.tpl.php` allows to theme only the term itself, not the actual list of nodes. So how can I theme that list of nodes?

Note that I don't want to theme individual nodes (that's not the scope of the question). I want to theme the list of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The return from `node_view_multiple` is supposed to be a dumb collection of node render arrays, it's not meant to be themeable in and of itself (at least not on a generic level, obviously case-by-case you can do it). The function sepecifically *doesn't* get involved with the theming, as that should be up to the caller to determine. So using `#theme` or `#theme_wrappers` on the outer array is the correct thing to do.

There isn't anything you can do to target other modules' use of `node_view_multiple()` in this respect, short of:

1. Patching the module code
2. Patching `node_view_multiple` itself so it has a default theme function, which you can then hook into.
3. Use a broader attack like `hook_page_alter()` to make specific changes to specific arrays when it makes sense to.

Comment: Option 1 makes little sense as I need generic solution.
Option 2 would be the best option, but there is no change this would go into the core :( 
Option 3 the same as option 1 - would work only for predetermined situations.
Anyway, thanks for the clues.